Banach–Tarski paradox and the Solovay model?
The paradox relies on the Axiom of Choice (AC) applied to uncountable families of sets (Uncountable Axiom of Choice).
Would the paradox lose its foundation following Robert Solovay's proof of the consistency of the Axiom of Choice (AC) with the denial of uncountable sets (AC ⇒ UAOC, but UAOC ⇏ AC)?
Without AC, it seems impossible to partition the sphere as required. Does the Solovay model, then, demonstrate that the paradox is inherently contradictory and invalid?

What is satisfied in the Solovay model is not AC but rather the weaker Axiom of Dependent Choice (for countable families of sets).  The full AC is not satisfied in the Solovay model.  Indeed the Banach-Tarski paradox does not hold in the Solovay model.

I don't think this question is somehow inherently unclear.

The Banach–Tarski paradox is a theorem of $\sf ZFC$. Validity is a question of your base assumptions.
The Solovay model is famous for satisfying "every set of reals is Lebesgue measurable" (while preserving a fragment of the Axiom of Choice, called Dependent Choice, which is sufficient for developing measure theory as we are used to thinking about it). This means that the Banach–Tarski paradox is false in this model. But, again, validity is dipping into the philosophy of mathematics and set theory, and worse: it dips into your personal beliefs about mathematics and the Axiom of Choice.
In Cohen's first model, where even the Axiom of Countable Choice fails pretty badly, the Banach–Tarski paradox still holds. So the Banach–Tarski paradox is not equivalent to "uncountable choice", since that would mean that it is false in this model.
To a large extent, however, the Banach–Tarski paradox is a huge red herring. Variants of the paradox using Baire category instead of Lebesgue measurability are outright provable, no choice needed. And even worse, if you want to just assume that all sets of reals are Lebesgue measurable, you can partition the real numbers into non-empty sets and have strictly more of these sets than you have points. This is a different partition paradox, if you will. The real thing is that intuition is different from reality, and infinity defies our innate intuition. At least until we forget it and develop a better one. But the same can be said about cooking, just as well.

The axiom of choice includes both countable and uncountable cases, i.e. choosing elements from any set of non-empty sets regardless of cardinality
You can have DC or AC, which extends to uncountable sets
DC allows the construction of sequences in which each element depends on the previous element in a more useful binary relationship than the countable axiom of choice (due to Baier's theorem), which says that every countable set of non-empty sets has a choice function, also can u explain how the tarski paradox is not equivalent to "uncountable choice", what do u mean by that...

I'm not sure if you're trying to teach me about choice principles or if you're asking a question. To your actual question at the end, the OP had hinted that somehow "uncountable axiom of choice" is the culprit, and my point is that in Cohen's model even countable choice fails badly, while BT is still provable. So phrasing this as "uncountable choice is the problem" is not a good way of thinking about this.

Wait, is the Baire category version of Banach-Tarski paradox provable without any form of choice? Sounds impressive to me. And just to clarify: Is it provable even without countable choice?

@Hanul: Well, yes, if you allow "up to a meager set" kind of mistake. At least that what I remember Matt Foreman telling me about a decade ago.
